# Character frequency in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm so stuck on this task. I have a task where I need to write a program in python 2.7 which prompts a user to input a string and then the program needs to return the number of times the letters in that string occur. for example the word "google.com" must return 'o': 3, 'g': 2, '.': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 1, 'm': 1, 'c': 1

I know i need to use the list() function but all i have so far is:

```
   string = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
   newString = list(string)
```

and then i get stuck from there because I don't know how to make the program count the number of times the letters occur. I know there must be a for loop in the syntax but I'm not sure how I'm going to use it in this case.
**NB:** We haven't been introduced to dictionaries or imports yet so please keep it as simple as possible. Basically the most round about method will work best.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this problem directly with the help of `count` function.

You can start with an empty dictonary and add each character of the entered string and its count to the dictionary.

This can be done like this..!

```
string = raw_input("Enter a string: ")

count_dict = {}

for x in string:
    count_dict[x] = string.count(x)

print count_dict

#input : google.com
# output : {'c': 1, 'e': 1, 'g': 2, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 3, '.': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Update*:
Since you haven't been introduced to dictionary and imports, you can use the below solution.

```
for i in set(string):
print("'{}'".format(i), string.count(i), end=",")
```

Use Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
string = "google.com"
print(Counter(string))
```

Other way, create a dictionary and add chars looping through your string.

```
dicta = {}
for i in string: 
    if i not in dicta:
        dicta[i] = 1
    else: 
        dicta[i] += 1
print(dicta)
```

Comment: *" ...We haven't been introduced to dictionaries or imports yet "*

Comment: I tried it on my python shell, it works perfectly but we haven't been taught about importing yet. So i don't know if my lecture will accept this answer... is there a more round about method?

Comment: @ZeeDhlomo I have updated the solution, see if that works for you. I am iterating through unique chars and counting in the original string.